# Regex_Extract Using PIG

Tags: regex, hadoop, count, apache-pig

I am using PIG to look for a string in a set of records and then output the name of the file(which is appended to the end of each record using a UDF) and the count of the matching string. The file name looks as follows 2015-03-04.23_55_05.Abhi_Ram.Info.json.

Below is my pig script:

```
REGISTER UDF;

input_data= LOAD 'input_dir' using classname();

record_match = FILTER input_data by $0 matches '$Search_string';

group_record = GROUP record_match ALL;

record_count = FOREACH record_match GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'((\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\\.(\\d.*)\.(\\w.*)\\.(\\w.*)\\.(json))',1), COUNT(record_match);

dump record_count;
```

I want to output

> 2015-03-04.23_55_05.Abhi_Ram.Info.json, count($Search_string).

Am I missing something in the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt get why you want to apply regex to the first field from source. Is your first field has the filename pattern ?. Because,

**$0 -> denotes the first record in  a row.**

Then,If you want the source filename to be in output record.The easy way would be

```
read = LOAD 'inp.data' USING PigStorage(',','-tagsource');
```

which will append your source filename to the record starting.

```
2015-03-04.23_55_05.Abhi_Ram.Info.json, count($Search_string)
```

As per your question , the REGEX_EXTRACT would be :

```
read = load 'test.data' using PigStorage(',');
date = foreach read generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}).(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})_(\\d{2}).(\\w.*)_(\\w.*).(\\w.*).json',0)) as      (filename_dt:chararray);
dump date;
```